# circle of inversion

Tags: geometry

Determine the equation of the circle reflection of the line $x = 2$ if the
circle of reflection is $x^2 + y^2 + 2x = 0$ which in standard form is $(x+1)^2+y^2=1$ where $radius=1$ and center is $(-1,0)$.

Since $x=2$ is on the outside of the circle of reflection I am not sure what to do.

Comment: The vertical line $x=2$ does not intersect the circle with radius $1$ and center at $(-1,0)$.

Comment: I don't understand if you want to invert the line $x=2$ using geometric inversion by the circle or if you want to reflect the circle on the line.

Comment: I believe invert the line $x=2$. Yeah I completely screwed up. Since $x=2$ is on the outside of the circle the inverse image should be inside $x^2+2x+y^2=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the circle of inversion has radius $1$ and is centered at $(-1,0)$ the line $x=2$ does not intersect the circle. Furthermore, the point $(2,0)$ is inverted to a point inside the circle.

Since the inversion of the line is a circle containing the center of inversion (i.e. $(-1,0)$) you only need to invert the point $(2,0)$ to obtain the equation of the circle coming from the inversion of the line.

[image]

Comment: So basically find the equation of the circle going through the point of inversion of $(2,0)$ and $(-1,0)$?

Comment: @user60887, yes, that's it. You could choose any other point on the line to invert but that one is the easiest one since its inversion would also be on the $x$-axis.

Comment: do I use $(OP)(OP')=r^2$ where O=origin and $P'=(2,0)$?

Comment: No. You have to use the center of inversion, that is, $(-1,0)$, instead of the origin $O=(0,0)$.

Comment: oh what I meant was finding the inverse of $(2,0)$. Im having some trouble

Comment: If the center of inversion (that is, the center of the circle used to inversion) is $Q$ and the radius of this circle is $r$ than the inversion of a point $B$ is the point $B'$ which satisfies $d(B,Q)d(B',Q)=r^2$.

Comment: $d(B,Q)=r^2/(d(B',Q)$. Since $r=1$ we have $1^2/(sqrt(x_2+1)^2+(y_2-0)^2)$. So I just solve for $x_2 and y_2$?

Comment: Yes, but in this case is easier since the point $B'$ must be on the ray from $Q$ to $B$. So it also has $y$ coordinate zero.

Comment: So I get $(-2/3,0)$.

Comment: OK. Note that Geogebra works with decimal numbers and uses an approximation.

Comment: So I get $(-2/3,0)$. What I did was just the distance formula. $1/3= $\sqrt[2]{(x_2+1)^2+(y_2)^2}. Since we know $y_2=0$ we just solve for $x_2$ which I got $(1/9)=(x_2+1)^2$. Solving for x I got two solutions but since the distance is positive I get $(-2/3,0)$.

Comment: wait what do i use to find the equation through $(-2/3,0)$ and $(-1,0)$?

Comment: Find the center of the circle.

Comment: I get $(x+(5/6))^2+y^2=1/9$ because $(-2/3,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ are the endpoints.

Comment: oops $r^2=1/36$